# Is it possible to have DialogFlow read your emails and create responses?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I've been playing around with DialogFlow but I don't see any way for it to receive my support emails.  Am I missing something or is that not allowed?

How do I get DialogFlow to receive my emails?

Answer (score 0):

Dialogflow is not designed for this particular usecase. It is designed for creating chat agents, so you get out of the box integration with messenger, slack etc.
However you can programmatically send emails to Dialogflow using [SDK](https://dialogflow.com/docs/sdks) and receive the responses.